# HTTP Post Links in a List Display Template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Projects entity. The list of Projects is displayed in a Scaffolded List View as shown below. The Edit-Details-Delete are ActionLinks produced by the template.Each is linked to a new controller action and loads another View

```
ProjectName  | Created By | Created On | Status |
-------------|------------|------------|--------|--------------------
Test Project | USER1      | 12/31/2010 |  NEW   | Edit |Details |Delete
```

Each Project has a status- New,Approved,Denied.
I want to add links to the list called Approve and Denied which do not load a view. They just change the status of the project. I believe these will be HTTP Post Links. I have googled and not found a good working example of this.

```
ProjectName  | Created By | Created On | Status |
-------------|------------|------------|--------|------------------------------------
Test Project | USER1      | 12/31/2010 |  NEW   | Edit |Details |Delete|Approve|Denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use AJAX:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "approve project", 
    "Approve", 
    new { projectId = item.ProjectId }, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }
)
```

and you will of course have a corresponding controller action that will take care of approving a project:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Approve(int projectId)
{
    ...
}
```

You could also use the `OnSuccess` and `OnFailure` properties of the `AjaxOptions` to define respective javascript functions that will be called in case of those events.

Needles to say that for the `Ajax.*` helpers to do anything useful you need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
```

and must have enabled unobtrusive AJAX in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not come across Ajax.ActionLink in my readings yet

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink` helper method produces the HTML markup for anchor tag and clicking on them will usually do an **HTTPGET** method. If you want to do **HTTPPOST** action, You can have an link generated by `Html.ActionLink` helper and using javascript, override the default link behaviour to do an `HTTPPost` to another action method which changes the status in your database. you can use the [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to prevent the default link behavior (navigate the new page)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Approve","Approve","Project",new { @id="someid"},new { @class="delClass"})
@Html.ActionLink("Denied","Denied","Project",new { @id="someid",anotherParam="someval"},new { @class="delClass"}))
```

Assuming your Controller name is `Project`.

Have some jQuery code to override the default link behaviour and do an AJAX posting (HTTP Post) to the `action` method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

    $(".delClass").click(function(e){

       e.preventDefault();  // prevent the default behaviour
       $.post(($this).attr("href"),function(data){
           //Do whatever with the resutl received from the action method call.
           //alert(data);  // may be alert ?
       });

    });

 });    
</script>
```

Have your `Action` method to handle this now

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Approve(string id)
{
  //Do the backend transaction with the id value.

  return Content("Approved");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Denied(string id,string anotherParam)
{
  //Do the backend transaction with the parameters value.

  return Content("Denied");
}
```